# Returning data from a function and assigning it to a variable in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS, and I am trying to return the data from a function to another function, and store it in a variable. But I am getting exception:

> TypeError: $scope.message is not a function

Code:

```
   <h3 class="panel-title">{{welcome}}</h3>

      $scope.message = function(){
               return "welcome Ramakrishna";
            } 

      $scope.message().then((result) => {
                $scope.welcome=result
            }).catch((err) => {
                $scope.welcome=err;
            });
```

Comment: You are calling the function before initializing it. You should move `$scope.message = ...` before `$scope.message()`

Comment: please explain with code

Comment: $scope.message = function(){
           return "welcome Ramakrishna";
        };  $scope.message().then((result) => {
            $scope.welcome=result
        }).catch((err) => {
            $scope.welcome=err;
        });

Comment: no not working if i do as like what you said

Comment: @Nikhil Aggarwal can you please guide me ?

Comment: Can you replicate the same issue here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192214/discussion-between-abhiram-and-nikhil-aggarwal).

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is get the value of the string returned by the `$scope.message()` function, you can simply do

`$scope.welcome = $scope.message();`

`$scope.message()` already returns a string, hence you don't need to give a `.then()`.

Hence try this code:

```
<h3 class="panel-title"> {{welcome}}</h3>

$scope.message = function() {
  return "welcome Ramakrishna";
}

$scope.welcome = $scope.message();
```